# FormArray values getting null Error: Cannot find control with name '0'

Tags: angular, forms, null, formarray

I am not able to get the FormArray field Values while submitting the form. I am getting empty values in Form Array Fields.

Whenever Iam clicking on addHobbies button iam getting an error: Cannot find control with name '0'

signupForm.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
            <span class="help-block">Email Required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div FormArrayName="hobbies">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="form-group col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addHobbies()">Add Hobbies</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="form-group col" *ngFor="let hobby of hobbyControls.controls; let i=index">
                {{i}}
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

signupform.component.ts

```
export class ReactiveformsComponent implements OnInit {
    
  signupForm : FormGroup;
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  
     ngOnInit(): void {

        this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
            'email': [''],
            'hobbies': this.fb.array([])
        })

    }
    addHobbies(){
        //const hobbyControl = this FormControl('');
        (<FormArray>this.signupForm.get('hobbies')).push(this.fb.control(''));
    }
    get hobbyControls(){
        return this.signupForm.get('hobbies') as FormArray;
    }

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.signupForm.value);
    }
```

output

{"email":"john@gmail.com","hobbies":["",""]}

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, instead of i use hobby here

```
<div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="form-group col" *ngFor="let hobby of hobbyControls.controls; let i=index">
                {{i}}
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="hobby">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error for `FormArrayName`.

```html
<div FormArrayName="hobbies">
  ...
</div>
```

---

### Solution

Change it to `formArrayName` so the directive will work.

```html
<div formArrayName="hobbies">
  ...
</div>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cip9ry?file=src/app/reactiveforms/reactiveforms.component.html)

---

### References

[Angular Form Array](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/)